# PHP/MySQL: Update front end upon database change

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application developed using Yii 2.0 that has a view page displaying information for a live score board. The information is read from MySQL database which is updated from another application. In order to keep the information on the scoreboard current, I'm using the following JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#general-info').load('info?id=1');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Basically, I'm probing the server every second and updating the values returned from the info url on response.

I'm wondering if there's a better and more efficient way to do this. It does not have to be Yii2.0 related solution, I just need the idea and I'll make it work in my current context. Possibly some kind of a database trigger that would inform the front end to poll the database for new information or kind of event that I can somehow subscribe to?

Comment: I think every 1 second is a bit of an overkill, wouldn't the load itself probably take longer?

Comment: I'd think of a `timestamp` flag, compare it on every request and only update it when it's changed since the last pull. If I'm not very mistaken, this is the same as big sites like Facebook do it.

Comment: It is working quite alright at the moment. I'm updating about 7 or 8 numbers and that's all that there is to it but I do agree that sending requests every one second is a bit too much. However, I do need to display changes on the front end as soon as they happen so I can't really extend the wait time to longer.

Comment: If I take the timestamp approach I would still be sending requests every second. I might be updating the front end or not but the traffic and server probing would still be there.

Comment: I guess you can't avoid sending some bits on a secondly base. As far as I know, the only thing you can do is minimise it by only sending/requesting the timestamp and only push/pull the much bigger content if it's actually changed.

Comment: You could, however, check how stock sites update their stocks, as they actually have to be updated *immediately* when they've changed.

Comment: Sorry for spamming, but I maybe found something for your interest: [***Comet***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Comment: Yes, thank you! Definitely a good read. I'm going through this example currently: http://webcooker.net/ajax-polling-requests-php-jquery/

Seems a lot better than polling the server every second or so.